# Get all rows after a column value occurs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
Col1  Col2

128   False
129   True
130   True
183   False
184   True
202   False
203   True
204   True
```

and I would like to have lists (or a list of tuples) like:

```
(128, 129, 130) , (183, 184) , (202, 203, 204)
```

So, my question is: How can I slice a dataframe by a column value and get all rows after (including) that column value?

The column value in this case is 'False'. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups by each `False` values and aggregate `tuple`s:

```
L = df.groupby((~df['Col2']).cumsum())['Col1'].agg(tuple).tolist()
print (L)
[(128, 129, 130), (183, 184), (202, 203, 204)]
```

Or if need consecutive values by `Col1` use:

```
L = df.groupby(df['Col1'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())['Col1'].agg(tuple).tolist()
print (L)
[(128, 129, 130), (183, 184), (202, 203, 204)]
```

Comment: @jezrael - is there a link you can provide to help me understand your answer. I think the answer is great - but I have no idea how that worked :)

Comment: @jezrael Very clever use of `(~df['Col2']).cumsum()`. +1 from me.

Comment: @ScottC, `(~df['Col2']).cumsum()` computes cumulative sum of [1,0,0,1,0,1,00] (which are "NOT" of `col2` with Boolean converted to [0,1]). The cumulative sum creates [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3] and now can be grouped.